# `pip install` in a Conda environment does not produce an importable package?

Tags: pip, conda, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am trying to install [spinningup](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/user/installation.html) inside a Conda environment, which is only currently available as a pip install (not a Conda package). The instructions specify to do a simple pip install:

```
git clone https://github.com/openai/spinningup.git
cd spinningup
pip install -e .
```

The `setup.py` file in this repo specifies [a package name](https://github.com/openai/spinningup/blob/master/setup.py) called `spinup`. However:

1. I don't seem to be able to import this, as VSCode does not show it as a valid package (`spinup could not be resolved`).
2. I don't see it in the list of Conda packages when looking under `conda list`
3. I don't see it under `/usr/local/*.

Am I missing something? I thought `pip install` would create importable Python modules?

Comment: Show us the output of `pip show spinningup`

Comment: And show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Also, `spinningup` is obviously not the same name as `spinup`.

Comment: 1. `pip show spinningup`: `WARNING: Package(s) not found: spinningup`

2. `import sys; print(sys.path)`: `['', '/Users/victor/Desktop', '/Users/victor/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python36.zip', '/Users/victor/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6', '/Users/victor/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Users/victor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/Users/victor/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages'`

I noticed that `sys.path` does not contain the `spinningup` directory. I wonder if this is because Conda does not preserve paths after deactivation?

Comment: I also notice that if I look under `/Users/victor/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, I see `spinup.egg-link`.

Comment: Does it work outside of VSCode? At shell, what do you get from: `conda run -n spinningup python -c 'import spinup; print(spinup.__spec__)'`?

Comment: The packaging of this project seems faulty to me. The `setup.py` script lists `spinup` as an import module (in `py_modules`), but it is obviously an import package (and should be listed in `packages` as well as all its import sub-packages).